# Is there any way to show data like this in listview?

Tags: listview, yii2

Hi I am completely new to Yii2 and I want to show the titles of the latest 10 posts with links to view the page. I found a way to do that but it's not good. Is there a better way to do this?

my controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{

     $dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query'=>Post::find(),
         'pagination'=>[
         'pageSize'=>9,
         ],
         ]);
     return $this->render('index',[
        'dataProviderlatenew'=>$dataProviderlatenew,
        ]);

}
```

index.php:

```
<ul id="ticker01" class="news_sticker">
<?php echo ListView::widget([
'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderlatenew,
'itemView'=>'latest_news',
'summary' => '',
'itemOptions' => [
     'tag' => false
 ],
 'pager' => [
 'options' => [
        'tag' => 'div',
         'style' => 'display: none;',
        'id' => 'pager-container',
        'class'=>'',
    ],
 ],
 ]);?>

  </ul>
```

latest_news.php

```
 <li><a href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/post/show','title'=>$model->title])?>"><?=$model->title?></a></li>
```

If there is a better way please say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to

1.) get the data using the select parameters and sort by create date n time.

2.) after the selection of row run a loop through all records selected and echo each row using while loop in same function and echo out the li items in the loop and call the function between the UL tags in html

In index.html

```
<ul>
    <?php
function in php controller();
?>
</ul>
```

In controller php file create a function

```
<?php
function called from html ul {
$sql = select query for getting data
$result = Db connection query
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<li>'.$row['column_name'].'<li>';
}
}
```

This function will give you a list of all the news which u want to show

You can also write functiondirectly in the ul tags instead of calling function from another file

Then using bootstrap or jquery set pagination to it

Comment: sorry i don't know how can do that. please say how make this?

Comment: please say one example i need it